# F# Adding to a Mutable List

Tags: f#

I'm writing a console based calculator application for a university project and have run into a bit of an error.

When a user selects an option from the menu (1,2,3,4 etc), they are able to input 2 numbers and either add, subtract, divide or multiply the sum. After each successful sum is solved and displayed, I want them to be added to my List `sumHistory`.

Here is my code currently, I feel like it should work but I'm obviously running into something small and silly preventing the list from being displayed when told to!

```
let sumHistory = new List<string>()

match input with
|"1" -> Console.WriteLine("Please enter 2 integers: ")
        let a= Console.ReadLine()
        let b= Console.ReadLine()
        let A: int = int32 a
        let B: int = int32 b
        let C = (add A B)
        let D = (string A + " + " + string B + " = " + string C)
        Console.WriteLine(D)
        sumHistory.Add(D)      
|"2" -> Console.WriteLine("Please enter 2 integers: ")
        let a= Console.ReadLine()
        let b= Console.ReadLine()
        let A: int = int32 a
        let B: int = int32 b
        let C = (sub A B)
        let D = (string A + " - " + string B + " = " + string C)
        Console.WriteLine(D)
        sumHistory.Add(D)  
|"3" -> Console.WriteLine("Please enter 2 integers: ")
        let a= Console.ReadLine()
        let b= Console.ReadLine()
        let A: int = int32 a
        let B: int = int32 b
        let C = (div A B)
        let D = (string A + " / " + string B + " = " + string C)
        Console.WriteLine(D)
        sumHistory.Add(D)  
|"4" -> Console.WriteLine("Please enter 2 integers: ")
        let a= Console.ReadLine()
        let b= Console.ReadLine()
        let A: int = int32 a
        let B: int = int32 b
        let C = (mul A B)
        let D = (string A + " * " + string B + " = " + string C)
        Console.WriteLine(D)
        sumHistory.Add(D)  
|"5" -> sumHistory |> Seq.iteri (fun index item -> printfn "%i: %s" index sumHistory.[index])
|"6" -> let data = ReadInText()
        data.Read()
```

Comment: Refactoring the project and applying good SE principles is a whole nother chunk of marks, I'm just trying to get things working at the moment @FyodorSoikin :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**[SOLVED]**

After actually reading through my own code I realised it was just a silly mistake.

The List was declared within the `while` and therefore was being restarted cleared after every sum!

Moving `let sumHistory = new List<string>()` to the top of the document just underneath namespace declarations solved this.